# Why does sound system is not working on lumia 550?

Tags: lumia, microsoft-account

I have bought a fresh lumia 550 and it feels awesome. Recently I am getting problem on its sound system. All the sound system like mic, loudspeaker and earphone too are not working. I mean it is producing sounds something like shit.

I have restored many times but it doesn't seems to work. What the problem? Or its just another **Microsoft's**  failure product.